# why does Print pop-up open and close automatically in print helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing Script using Response.Write, It execute only on Response.End(); but after that my execution stops and it doesn't Redirect on mentioned page in asp.net c# I am very new to asp.net C# and hope I made the query clear. Please help.

BELOW I am sharing my PRINTHELPER class.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class PrintHelper
{
   public PrintHelper()
  {

  }

public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl)
{
    PrintWebControl(ctrl, string.Empty);
}

public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl, string Script)
{
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    if (ctrl is WebControl)
    {
        Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage); ((WebControl)ctrl).Width = w;
    }
    Page pg = new Page();        

    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    if (Script != string.Empty)
    {
        pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "PrintJavaScript", Script);
    }

    HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Attributes.Add("href", "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css");
    link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    pg.Controls.Add(link);
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);

    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.location.href = 
   'default.aspx'</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 }
}
```

Comment: comment out the last 2 lines that make the close, and the redirect (and there see if all is ok)

Comment: @Aristos, Tnx for reply, After commenting it works but when ever i press F5, the Form Resubbmission Alert box come, and on press of continue it again insert the same value twice.

Comment: @Aristos, Therefore I decide it to redirect on same page after the print is done, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I redirect it to same page after printing i.e. uisng **onafterprinting**

JUST REPLACE This CODE :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>
window.location.href = 'default.aspx'</script>");
```

WITH THIS CODE :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>
window.onafterprint = function(){window.location.href = 'default.aspx'}</script>");
```